# HTML5 Canvas drawing and updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, html5-canvas

Sorry for how vague the title is, but I'm not completely sure how to sum up what I'm trying ask.

First off, here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DqrEm/) of what I have so far.

I'm just starting off learning to use the HTML5 canvas element, as well as using js OOP.

As you can see from the fiddle, I create a rectangle class (so that I may create as many squares as possible, although I think that may be redundant), and reference it to draw. However, when I set the `height = width`, I always end up with a non-square. I'm relatively new to using the canvas, but I assume thats because the square's height and width are relative to the size of the canvas element, and so the canvas element's height and width must not be proportional (since their assigned percent values as opposed to definite pixels).

I can fix this by setting the size of the square to pixels, but then when my keypress event is called, the square doesn't move at all.

Also, I have the keypress event so that a user can move the square with the arrow keys. However, the up/down keys values seem to be inverted, even when I flip-flop them in the code? And the left/right keys don't do anything?

And, I also can only make the square move up/down once? Shouldn't my code allow me to increase my x/y values as long as the user keeps pushing the corresponding buttons?

If someone could check this out and give me some pointers as to what I'm doing wrong, that would be great! I'm trying a lot of new things with this, as its just a learning experience, so if you feel so inclined, help me learn!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You experienced a thing that often goes wrong with resizing a canvas - trying to use CSS for it. Using CSS for canvas drawing will scale it - not changing the resolution. For setting the resolution, use the `width=` and `height=` attributes in HTML.

As for the movements, it appears that `keyup` works better. However, for the `up` key, the `y` would decrement (top is `0`, bottom is something positive).

A few other things I'd like to highlight.

Using `canvas` as a variable name for the context is a little ambiguous. There is a difference between the canvas and its context used for drawing.

Also, you state `//browser doesn't support html5` if `ctx` does not exist. However, in case the browser does not support canvas/HTML5, the `.getContext('2d')` function call will fail already because it's not a function in that case. Your `else` statement will only get executed if the function *does* exist but does not return something. That will probably never be the case.

Empty `else` loops aren't very useful either, but that doesn't hurt :)

http://jsfiddle.net/DqrEm/4/

Comment: The `else` statement doesn't even need to be there because the content that is put within the opening and closing `canvas` tags is what's displayed if `canvas` isn't supported.

Comment: thanks! that works perfectly, although I'm not a huge fan of using `.keyup`, since the user has to repeatedly press the key to move the square, as opposed to being able to hold down the key...

Comment: @Jordan Foreman: Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/DqrEm/6/. By setting flags and running an interval, you can have a smooth animation. Also simultaneous keys are possible that way.

Comment: thats really nice! Thanks! I guess I was getting a little ahead of myself, as thats what I was going to try and work on next

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't with the size of your square, but with how you size your `canvas`. In your jsfiddle, when I changed the `canvas` starting line to `<canvas id="practice" width="500" height="500">` the square was drawn properly. I tried changing the `width` and `height` in the CSS from 100% to 500px but the square was still drawn incorrectly.

**Update:** Setting the `width` and `height` to 100% in the actual `canvas` tag(i.e `<canvas id="practice" width="100%" height="100%">`) works too.

Comment: let me try it...when I started reading about the canvas element, the width and height were always declared within the element tags, but isn't that method invalid markup?

Comment: Usually yes, but I believe it's allowed for `canvas`.